# Does 'entschuldigen+dass' make sense?

Tags: conjunction, verb-usage

For example:

> Ich möchte mich hiermit entschuldigen, dass ich an diesen Tag nicht kommen könnte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "sich entschuldigen, dass".

> Bitte entschuldige, dass ich dir auf den Fuß getreten bin.
>
> [Ich bitte um] Entschuldigung [dafür], dass ich dir auf den Fuß getreten bin.
>
> Ich möchte mich [dafür] entschuldigen, dass ich dir auf den Fuß getreten bin.

Your example

> Ich möchte mich ... entschuldigen, dass ich ... nicht kommen könnte.

still sounds odd, for two reasons:

"könnte" is wrong here, it's subjunctive, and that does not go together with Entschuldigung. Either use "konnte" (past tense) if you're making an excuse after the fact, or use "kann" to make an excuse in advance, e.g., cause you already know you won't make it that day.

"mich entschuldigen" (without "für etwas") already implies that you weren't there, or that you would like to leave.

> Entschuldigen sie mich bitte.

means that you want to leave a conversation or group of people, as in being excused from the table.

If your example is about e.g., telling a teacher that you cannot / could not come, I'd say your example sentence as

> Bitte entschuldigen Sie, dass ich an diesem Tag nicht kommen konnte / kann.

If you are telling a friend you're sorry you couldn't make it to an imporatnt event, I'd say

> Ich möchte mich dafür entschuldigen, dass ich nicht kommen konnte.

However, this would be for very important events (e.g., wedding) or when you promised to be there and had to change plans on a short notice.

Comment: Du schreibst am Anfang “*sich* entschuldigen, dass”, so sind Deine Beispiele aber nicht, und es wäre auch falsch.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich hab noch mal nachgebessert